# Group nodes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Regards, I need help with a xslt for group nodes:

I have the following Input XML

```
    <ZMM:Request xmlns:ZMM="http://any.com" PAR_VAR="X">
       <PR_BUDAT>
          <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="202" HIGH="204"/>
       </PR_BUDAT>
       <PR_BUDAT>
          <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="20170108" HIGH="20200108"/>
       </PR_BUDAT>
       <PR_FEDE>
          <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="201121212" HIGH="20233232"/>
       </PR_FEDE>
       <PR_FEDE>
          <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="201121212" HIGH="20233232"/>
       </PR_FEDE>
       <PR_FEDE>
          <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="6455646565" HIGH="8979879879"/>
       </PR_FEDE>
       <PR_DEFE>
          <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="2222222222" HIGH="3333333333"/>
       </PR_DEFE>
           .
           .
           .
    </ZMM:Request>
```

I need the following output:

```
<ZMM:Request xmlns:ZMM="http://any.com" PAR_VAR="X">
   <PR_BUDAT>
      <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="202" HIGH="204"/>
      <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="20170108" HIGH="20200108"/>
   </PR_BUDAT>
   <PR_FEDE>
      <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="201121212" HIGH="20233232"/>
      <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="201121212" HIGH="20233232"/>
      <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="6455646565" HIGH="8979879879"/>
   </PR_FEDE>
   <PR_DEFE>
      <row SIGN="I" OPTION="BT" LOW="2222222222" HIGH="3333333333"/>
   </PR_DEFE>
           .
           .
           .
</ZMM:Request>
```

The idea is collect all content of nodes with same name into one only node
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Make sure we understand if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Hi, is xslt 1.0 i dont have attempt to post because all my attempts are failed and i dont have any idea how begin. thanks

Comment: Begin here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: thanks.. was usefull